# Regular expression in NP++ to find query that is NOT inside an <a> </a> tag in html

Tags: html, regex, search, notepad++

I need a regular expression in NP++ to find query that is NOT inside an anchor or a hyperlink tag in an html file..  So it finds any gives search query (a word or a couple of words, like: "test", or "Ask a question", that is not linked..  Or in other words: finds the search query that is not linked, and ignores the linked one.

Given that links could be direct links, that tag is not directly before and after the query, or in more than one line.

Example:

```
<p>any text here, something else..</p>
<p>more
<a href="../folder/filename.html">test</a>

to find through other test.&nbsp; With much
<a href="http://www.site.com/folder/filename45.html">
                <font color="#800000">Ask a question</font></a> more test</p>
<p>and test to Ask a question here.</p>
```

Comment: That's impossible. The best you can get is `between </a> or $  and <a> or $, without intervening <a> tags`. Even then, it's not worth it. Stick to `after </a>`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no perfect solution with regular expressions. It would be better to do this with a programming language and a DOM parser.

Here is about the best you can get:

```
test(?!((?!<a\W).)*</a)
```

It uses two [negative lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match `test` if there is no `</a` before the next opening `<a`. Make sure to check `. matches newline` and to update to Notepad++ 6.

This will start to fail, if you have `<a` or `</a` in comments or within attribute strings. Not even speaking of invalid HTML.

Comment: +1 for your solution but noteworthy that this will break on a nested structure...

Comment: @Christoph as far as I know, nested `<a>` are invalid HTML (which is what I am referring to in the last sentence) ;)